# What episode is about "Lucky Bastard Fever"?

Tags: crayon-shin-chan

I have a question about a lucky bastard fever episode in *Crayon Shin-chan*, I was wondering if you could help me find what episode this is from.

It was about that bird man bad guy and Lollipop was at her house and some professor guy was there too, but then he left and then he came back from the house side of the house. Lollipop did not know how he did it but later it  turned out that the other professor was the main bad guy in trying to find a weakness on the action bastered suite.